# Scroll to particular vertical position after browser refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, infinite-scroll

I am building an infinite-scroll style list for a mobile web app (using angular). The catch is that the initial starting position of the list that the user should see is somewhere in the middle. This works fine on initial load of the page (setting `scrollTop`). However on page refresh, the browser attempts to set the scroll position to the last position the user was viewing.

My hack was to set a large enough delay on setting `scrollTop` so that it happens after the browsers attempt, but this feels clunky. Is there another *angular* way, or regular js way to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the *"auto scroll to the last position the user was viewing"* is vary in different browsers.

It may happen after a `DOMContentLoaded` event, or after `window.onload`, or both (happen twice e.g. in Chrome).

You could delay your position setting to after `window.onload` with `setTimeout`.

A plain vanilla JavaScript would look like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    window.scrollTo(window.pageXOffset, 500);
  }, 0);
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out, and if it works well will mark your answer.